# Php slow io operation

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, io

I have nginx server. With following configurations:

```
32 GB RAM
Intel Xeon E3-1231v3 (3.4)
```

It is a dedicated server and hosts only one website. Recently, the average load was pretty high (uptime command). I debugged all the php code and there is no bug as it is mostly static website with rewrite mode. It only fetches data from MySql. I used iotop command and it showed the following command was eating all the io.

```
find /var/lib/php5 -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -ignore_readdir_race -type f -cmin +300 -delete
```

What does it has to do with nginx or php? How could I stop it? It runs after sometime automatically.

MySql Conf file [settings are here](http://dragonites.com/mysql_conf.txt).

Comment: paste your my.cnf file maybe the bottle neck is mysql

Comment: @matanco, I have updated my question with the link to MySql conf file. Please have a look.

Comment: yes you have to change this file and give to mysql-server more memory to work with, what is the size of the DB?

Comment: DB total size is 30MB only. I think the above commands tries to remove sessions stored in /var/lib/php5. Could you please explain the relationship of php5 dir and MySql? Also what parameters I must change to give more memory to MySql-Server?

Comment: follow this https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/28/10-mysql-settings-to-tune-after-installation/, but if the size is 30M i don't think this is the problem.